# Cant create conda env in dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda

I have an `environment.yml` in my applications folder

I have this in my dockerfile:

```
RUN conda env create
RUN source activate myenvfromymlfile
```

When I run the container though the env is not activated. If I `do conda env list` Is see `/opt/conda` is activated:

```
root@9c7181cf86aa:/app# conda env list
# conda environments:
#
myenvfromymlfile         /opt/conda/envs/myenvfromymlfile
root                  *  /opt/conda
```

If I attach to the container I can manually run `source activate myenvfromymlfile` and it works, but why doesn't that work in the RUN directive??

In examples, I see this often in dockerfiles that require conda:

```
CMD [ "source activate your-environment && exec python application.py" ]
```

Can someone explain why it is necessary to use && to make it a single command? And why running "source activate" in a RUN directive does not work? I want to have my dockerfile look like this:

```
RUN conda env create
RUN source activate myenvfromymlfile
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["application.py"]
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on dockerfiles but I think what you're looking for is here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/. see the paragraph titled, `Before multi-stage builds`

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with my question. "source activate myenvfromymlfile" needs to be run as a single command with "python application.py" using && in order to work and I dont understand why

Comment: regarding the "&& to make it a single command", each layer add additional overhead and environment variables do not get passed between layers.

Comment: You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67059518/6503329) for a detailed explanation for the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the below Dockerfile

```
RUN conda env create
RUN source activate myenvfromymlfile
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["application.py"]
```

Statement #1 `conda env create`. Create the environment and changes files on the disk.

Statement #2 `source activate myenvfromymlfile`. Loads some stuff in the bash sessions. No disk changes done here

Statement #3 and #4 specifies what happens when you run the container

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["application.py"]
```

So now when you run the container. Anything that you did in step#2 is not there, because a shell was launched to run step #2, when it completed the shell was closed. Now when you run the image a new shell is started and it is brand new shell with now no knowledge that in past inside your dockerfile you ran `source activate myenvfromymlfile`

Now you want to run this `application.py` in the environment you created. The default shell of docker is `sh -c`. So when you set `CMD` as below

```
CMD [ "source activate your-environment && exec python application.py" ]
```

The final command executed at start of container becomes

```
sh -c "source activate your-environment && exec python application.py"
```

Which activates the environment in current shell and then runs your program.

Comment: So that makes perfect sense, I thought it was the same session for ALL the run commands but I guess not! This kinda stinks though because I'd really like to have a generic image that can execute any python application you pass it (like you can do with an ENTRYPOINT of "python" and CMD of someApp.py). How can I make this conda container behave this way?

Comment: You need to make a shell script and use that as the ENTRYPOINT, so any CMD actually goes as parameter to the shell script and then in the script you can do whatever you want